# Promise handle http errors of a get call (within a foreach)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, httprequest

I have a function for reading a csv file, from every line I read an url, and then I do a get request.

This is the code:

```
function readCSV(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");
  var table = lines.map(line => line.split(","));
  var requests = table.map(row => request({         // -> [request, request]
        method: 'GET',
        uri: "https://www." + row[1],
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }));
 

    return Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {  // -> [response, response]
        console.log('it worked');
        responses.forEach(response => {
            var hrds = response.headers;
            console.log(hrds)
            console.log("---------------")
            // hrds is an object. print it, extract info from it, whatever
            // don't forget to look at the other properties of `response`, as well
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

My problem is: how can I handle http errors that may exist?
and then: if I have a web page that takes too long to respond, how can I skip it in order to continue with the next url?

Comment: If *any* promise in Promise.all rejects, it gets rejected overall with the first error. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the error, one trick is to return a predictable value on the `catch` and check for that value later on. Like this:

```js
function readCSV(csv) {
  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  var table = lines.map((line) => line.split(","));
  var requests = table.map((row) =>
    request({
      method: "GET",
      uri: "https://www." + row[1],
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    })
    .catch((err) => null) // Errors are ignored and resolved as `null`
  );

  return Promise.all(requests)
    .then((responses) => {
    
      responses.forEach((response) => {
        if(response === null) return; // If the response is null, skip it

        // ... handle successful responses here

      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```